# Pull large .js file into its own chunk with webpack

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I'm writing a single-page app which I've created with [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).  It loads a *very* large word list file, `scrabble-dictionary.js`, that never changes.  Compiling was taking forever every time I made a change to some other part of my code, so I want to pull that large file into its own compiled chunk.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to tell create-react-app to do this without running `npm run eject`, which pulls all the config files out so you can edit them.

Now I have a `webpack.config.dev.js` file.  I've used webpack before, but it's been a couple years, so I'm fairly rusty.  I've tried adding multiple entry points: one for `index.js`, which is what create-react-app added by default, and one for my word list file.  Oddly, webpack generates the two identical files which are the entire app including both the code for index.js and the word list file.

By default (immediately after running `npm run eject`), the webpack config file looks like this:

```
// ...
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    paths.appIndexJs
  ],
  output: {
    // Next line is not used in dev but WebpackDevServer crashes without it:
    path: paths.appBuild,
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  // ...
};
```

I've augmented my `paths.js` file to include:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  // custom entry points
  appWordsJs: resolveApp('src/scrabble-dictionary.js'),
};
```

Then I changed `webpack.config.dev.js` to

```
// ...
module.exports = {
  // ...
  entry: {
    webpackHotDevClient: [require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient')],
    vendor: [require.resolve('./polyfills')],
    main: [
        // Finally, this is your app's code:
        paths.appIndexJs
      ],

    dictionary: [paths.appWordsJs],
  },
  output: {
    // Next line is not used in dev but WebpackDevServer crashes without it:
    path: paths.appBuild,
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/[name].js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    plugins: [ new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('dictionary', paths.appWordsJs)]
  },
// ...
```

It doesn't seem to make a difference if I include the `plugins` or not.

I also tried setting `dictionary` to `[require.resolve(__dirname + '/../src/scrabble-dictionary.js')]` with the same result.